# android gradle build in command line error: UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, command-line

Build inside android studio works, but failed with command line build

```
> gradlew tasks

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

The line `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` causes the error. where does the `major.minor version 52.0` come from?

Comment: @NileshRathod how should that help? That question talks about failing **in AS**, this question is about failing **on commandline**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your JAVA_HOME variable.

The error means there are classes compiled with Java 8 (52.0) that you are trying to use with an older Java version.

When you use Android Studio obviously Java 8 is used to run Gradle, but when you use the Gradle wrapper from commandline, the value of JAVA_HOME is used to execute Gradle.

This is set to Java 7 or older on your machine and thus the build fails as soon as it tries to use the Java class that was compiled with Java 8, in your case a part of the Android Gradle plugin.

Comment: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin is compiled with Java8? or can it be a dependency jar compiled with Java 8?  All dependency jars are from remote repository (jcenter, maven, google). How to figure out which jar is compiled with Java8? JAVA_HOME is pointing to Java 7 on my computer. Thanks.

Comment: Does android support Java 8 now? If yes, I would like to use Java 8 for command line build.

Comment: Yes, it even requires Java 8 now. It is exactly the class `com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin` from the error message that was compiled with Java 8. Just set your `JAVA_HOME` accordingly and all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure gradle plugins are latest:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Comment: @eastwater did you try Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: invalidate cache inside android studio? The error is from command line build.