# Trouble running gradlew build in cli

Tags: java, android, gradlew

We are having a trouble running gradlew build. Our app is based on webview. When we run gradle build in cli, a following error constantly pops up

```
C:\app_n\app\src\main\java\com\example\app\MainActivity.java:3 error ';' 
expected import Android.extras.android.m2repository.com.android.support. 
appcompat-v7 error:app:compileDegugJavawithJavac failed.
```

Since the error seems to refer towards MainActivity.java file. Here is the entire code of that page.

```
package com.example.app;

import android.extras.android.m2repository.com.android.support.appcompat-v7; 
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ecitizen.in/")); // 
        Starts Implicit Activity startActivity(i); 
    } 
}
```

We have already downloaded the entire android support repository. Our 
 requirement is appcompat function which is required for using this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("ecitizen.in/"));
```

Comment: Can you post the first 5 lines of `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: package com.example.app;
import Android.extras.android.m2repository.com.android.support.appcompat-v7;
import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: Second line. `import android.extras.android.m2repository.com.android.support.appcompat-v7; ` should start with a lowercase `a`

Comment: In fact, that import statement looks very odd. What happens when you remove it? Can you post your entire `MainActivity.java` [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50745729/edit) if you're able to?

Comment: Please post that information as [an edit to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50745729/edit). It's pretty much unreadable in the comments.

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I suspect the problem is. However, you're probably missing quite a few imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imports are case-sensitive, and this particular import doesn't make any sense:

```
import Android.extras.android.m2repository.com.android.support.appcompat-v7;
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this, as it looks like you're trying to import the entire support v7 library. From what you've posted in the comments it looks like you're using `AppCompatActivity`, so your import should be this instead:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

You're also missing the import for your resources, so your Activity would not be able to load your layout file:

```
import com.example.app.R;
```

Assuming you're coding this in Android studio, you can import any missing dependencies by moving the carat to the part highlighted in red, pressing **alt** + **enter**, and selecting **Import Class**.

Comment: Hi. I did try to use this url. But immediately error: dependency does not exist shows up. I downloaded the support repository from sdk manager. It is residing in this path:android.extras.android.m2repository.com.android.support.appcompat-v7; And regarding android studio,we are not using it. The entire process is done through command line with help of android sdk.

Comment: Thing is, while I can understand wanting to build via a cli, coding the .java files also via a CLI is going to be a very painful process, not something I'd want to do myself. Dependency import in particular is going to be a pain to manage without a proper IDE. I'd advise you to rethink your approach. At the very least just delete that initial import.

Comment: Well, i would have loved to do with android studio, but thing is that i do not have necessary configurations to download android studio in my computer.An update, i tried import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; again, but a following error: that package does not exist pops up. Yes when we remove that import, it works, but what about using function:"Intent" which can only be called when AppCompat Activity exists. What shall i do.

Comment: Okay. Got the headstart from your point of importing dependencies. I removed AppCompat Activity import and included Intent | URI imports. It has built the app successfully. Thanks for your help. But i would appreciate if you could standby as i'm checking whether intent redirect works.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your JAVA_HOME variable is properly set.
As mentioned in the link below ,this might as well be a Java build error.

Link:

[android gradle build in command line error: UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722470/android-gradle-build-in-command-line-error-unsupportedclassversionerror)